# text-transform css not support in tablet browser

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using text-transform:uppercase in input box. it is not support in tablet browser.

Here is my HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
<input type="text" class="isCapital">
</body>
</html>
```

And CSS:

```
.isCapital{text-transform:uppercase;}
```

anybody have solution for this. please update your answers.

Answer (score 1):

You have:

```
                          <!-- v--- this was misspelled -->
<input type="text" class="isCaptial">
```

It should be:

```
<input type="text" class="isCapital" />
```

Comment: @Mathi Which browser are you using?

Comment: @Mathi try changing your CSS definition to: `.isCapital { text-transform: uppercase !important; }`.

Comment: default samsung tablet brower.

Comment: after change the css
.isCapital { text-transform: uppercase !important; }
also not working

Answer (score 0):

You misspelled capital.

Replace `isCaptial` with `isCapital`.

Answer (score 0):

You should not expect `text-transform` to affect form field values, since such values are not part of the HTML element’s content. I was surprised at seeing that in browsers I tested (Firefox, Chrome, IE, Opera on Win, and Android) it actually affects the value, whether specified in a `value` attribute or entered by the user. But such behavior is not specified in CSS specifications.

It is also potentially confusing and misleading to transform data that way. The user types “foo” but sees “FOO”, and the data actually sent on form submission is “foo”.

If you really wish to make the page behave that way, then the most cross-browser way is probably to use (in addition to the `text-transform` property) JavaScript code that converts characters to upper case as they are entered but stores the original input as well and intercepts form submission so that instead of the actual form, another form, created by the JavaScript code, as an invisible copy of the original form but with the data entered stored as such, gets submitted.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it can help or not, but would you like to try this ?
use Javascript / jQuery:

```
<script>
jQuery(function(){
  jQuery(".isCapital").html().toUpperCase();
});
</script>
```

Happy coding !